# iterate through dataframe and append to empty string

Tags: r

I want to iterate through a dataframe and append all strings in a column to an empty string.

For example:

```
Name <- c("Jon", "Bill", "Maria", "Ben", "Tina")
Age <- c(23, 41, 32, 58, 26)
df <- data.frame(Name, Age)
```

I want to have an output string:

```
emp_str = "Jon Bill Maria Ben Tina"
```

I did this:

```
emp_str <- ""
for (string in df$Name) {
  append(emp_str, string)
}
```

this didn't give me any result, the empty string remains empty. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your expected output? can you add some data to make it reproducible?

Comment: Try `paste(df$Name, collapse=" ")`

Comment: Or `stringr::str_flatten(df$Name, " ")`

Comment: `append()` adds elements to a vector, so you'd end up with `c("", "Jon", "Bill", "Maria", "Ben", "Tina")`  instead.  But as it doesn't do that in-place, you'd need `emp_str <- append(emp_str, name)` .

Answer (score 3):

Use the function paste with collapse = " "

```
Name <- c("Jon", "Bill", "Maria", "Ben", "Tina")
Age <- c(23, 41, 32, 58, 26)
df <- data.frame(Name, Age)

emp_str <- paste(df$Name, collapse = " ")
```